# how to 301 redirect a lot of old links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

The first week in December my company put their new website online. Now we knew we had to 301 redirect the old links that weren't put back onto the new website, so we did.

But now I face a new problem which gives me headaches..
When I check my broken links in Google Webmaster tools, I get about 50 dead links every day with the following URL structure:

```
http://www.example.nl/portfolio/item/client/1
```

The 1 at the end of the URL goes on to 10. So I have 10 links for that particular portfolio item I have to redirect in my `.htaccess`. The new URL structure is as follow:

```
http://www.example.nl/portfolio/client
```

Now I already have around 300-400 301 redirects in my `.htaccess` but it feels like I'm doing something wrong here.

Does anyone here have a more efficient method to get my links to redirect?

Comment: Thus both site have the same structure or what???
i.e oldsite.com/item1/page   ==  newsite.com/item1/page

Comment: hey, no.
Old website structure: oldsite.nl/portfolio/item/portfolioitem
new website structure: oldsite.nl/portfolio/portfolioitem

Comment: There is nothing else changes right

Comment: "but it feels like I'm doing something wrong here." - why do you say this? Because you have 300-400 redirects already? Judging by your comment, the word `client` in your question is variable, that is not literal?

Comment: Yes, 'client' is a variable (in like the client's name).

Comment: If the structure changes you need to use redirection based on regular expression like this RedirectMatch 301 ^/item/.* http://www.example.nl/portfolio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in the .htaccess file in the document root, with you other redirects:

```
RewriteRule ^(portfolio)/item/([-a-z]+)/\d+ /$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

This will redirect `/portfolio/item/<client>/<num>` to `/portfolio/<client>`. Where `<client>` and `<num>` are variable. It also assumes that `<client>` consists of just the lowercase letters `a` to `z` and the hyphen (`-`).

I'm assuming you are already using mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) for your other redirects. (It is not recommended to mix mod_alias (ie. `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`) and mod_rewrite redirects.)

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: wow thanks! 1 question, my client variables also have a - in them, to seperate the names, so for example: client-name-here
How do i get that in the code you just posted?

Comment: In that case, just change the regex `[a-z]+` to `[-a-z]+` (the hyphen needs to go at the start or end of the character class in order to match a literal hyphen.) I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to redirect as per your URL structure needs to be done with Reg expression in htaccess redirection

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/item/.* http://www.example.nl/portfolio/
```

Comment: The old and new site are on the same domain - the domain hasn't changed, just the URL structure. (But this also redirects all requests to the document root.)